# How to write mysql prepared statement using the same variable in many columns?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to select a word from an English dictionary in MySql. Meaning versions are saved in different columns. So i'm trying to write my prepared statement as following. But it's giving me error and so far I have not found better solution. 
My code is as following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `dic1` 
                    WHERE 
                    eng     LIKE '%?%' OR 
                    eng2    LIKE '%?%' OR
                    eng3    LIKE '%?%' OR
                    eng4    LIKE '%?%' OR
                    eng5    LIKE '%?%'";

                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $searchWord);
```

Can you suggest me a better way? Thank you.

Comment: Repeat the same variable 5 times

Comment: Versions might have been better in a separate table.

Comment: Definitely better as a separate table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

1. You are not binding 5 values while you are using 5 in your query;
2. You need to remove the quotes and put the wildcards where you bind your variables:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dic1` 
               WHERE 
               eng     LIKE ? OR 
               eng2    LIKE ? OR
               eng3    LIKE ? OR
               eng4    LIKE ? OR
               eng5    LIKE ?";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
        $stmt, 
        "sssss", 
        '%' . $searchWord . '%',
        '%' . $searchWord . '%',
        '%' . $searchWord . '%',
        '%' . $searchWord . '%',
        '%' . $searchWord . '%'
    );
   ```

Comment: Great. It is working. Dear mr.jeroen, thank you so much for your fast reply. Thank you again :)

Comment: I would use "%{$searchword}%"